# Turn off python 3.5 warning in pycharm

Tags: pycharm

I have a PyCharm warning

```
Python version 3.4, 3.5 do not support a 'F' prefix
```

I'm using Python 3.7.  I've seen the checkbox for whether to check warnings for Python 3.4, 3.5, 3.6, 3.7, etc., but I cannot find it.

How do I shut off this warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either disable or tune code compatibility inspection: `File - Settings - Editor - Inspections - Code compatibility inspection`.

Inspection that raises a warning could be found by clicking `Alt+Enter` on highlighting and selecting `Edit inspection profile setting` in the dropdown menu, see screenshot from the documentation: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/disabling-and-enabling-inspections.html#suppress-in-editor

Comment: I'm on OS X, so it's `PyCharm - Preferences - Editor - Inspections - Code compatibility inspection`. But that worked. Thanks!

Comment: On newer PyCharm versions it's on `PyCharm - Preferences - Editor - Inspections - Code is incompatible with specific Python version` and the versions are in the `Options` sections on the bottom right.